# How to import package with part "type" in Scala?

Tags: scala, import

how can I import the following package:

```
 org.hibernate.type.StringType
```

in Scala?  If I do:

```
 import org.hibernate.type.StringType
```

"type" is recognized as a keyword.  This is the second time I have run into this in two days.  My last solution was the change my (Java) package name.  This is no longer a valid solution!

Here is the message from Scala IDE:

```
 <error> is not a member of org{org.type}.hibernate{org.hibernate.type}
```

Comment: If that's literally the error message you received, it's hard to see how anyone would understand the underlying issue.  Please file a ticket, or at least add a comment to the end of [this one](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3092).

Comment: That is literally the error message I receive--although it's from ScalaIDE so I don't know if the source is ScalaIDE or scalac.  I knew what the issue was because "type" was colored as a keyword in the impor.

Comment: The root cause is that 'type' is a keyword in Scala but not Java. (As inferred by @RafałRawicki)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wrap the keyword with backquotes:

```
import org.hibernate.`type`.StringType
```

This trick also works when calling methods, which names are keywords in Scala.